# How to handle CSRF tokens in across 2 rails instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

Web requests made to my 2 Rails instances sometimes produce the following error (silently)

```
...
W, [2019-09-04T10:53:53.880137 #13871]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
I, [2019-09-04T10:53:53.880465 #13871]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
...
```

I believe this is because of the CSRF token generated from 1 instance and the above request was made to another instance.

How can I resolve this without disabling CSRF tokens?

The current setup is 2 virtual machines (on separate machines) running a copy of the same Rails app, sitting behind a load balancer. I have looked at the logs and this occurs at least 10 times a day.

Any help would be much appriciated

Comment: What load balancer do you use? There should be a simple option from load balancer setup that can forward request to the same instance for same client.

Comment: We use BinaryLane for hosting. They have a [load balancer solution](https://support.binarylane.com.au/support/solutions/articles/1000025661-load-balancer)

Answer (score 0):

I've never use BinaryLane, and I've tried to check their document about setting load balancer where I can show you, but cannot find one.

Here is the load balancer config I used in GCP:

[image]

Look for `Session affinity` option or something similar (see their explanation for each option), for me I choose `Generated cookie`. Hope this give you idea of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get in contact with BinaryLane to see if I can find out.

Comment: I heard back from BinaryLane. They said "The load balancer has a 60 second timeout on session stickiness (requests from one IP address will continue to be sent to the same real server within the 60 second window). After that point a request may end up on any server in the load balanced pool."

Comment: Do we have option to increase the timeout?

Comment: I'll ask. I have a good feeling the answer will be no. I get the feeling you believe the issue is the load balancer or that there are multiple apps running?

Comment: I used to have the same issue, where the second request got forwarded to different instance, hence Rails fail to verify CSRF token.

Comment: Another way to debug is to log both instances at the same time, then send request to test it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: BinaryLane said they do not allow users to modify the load balancer configuration. The next logical thing would be to deploy an Nginx server and do the load balancing myself. I want to take the path of least resistance where possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198979/discussion-between-david-milanese-and-coco).